# Sed command only works when split up into two steps

Tags: command-line, sed

Can someone explain to me why combining step 1 and step 2 as one sed command doesn't work:

```sh
sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{0,127\}$/& /;ta' \
-e '1,46d' -e '/Pharmacom/,+5d' -e 's/^M//g' \
-e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' -e 's/---*/\n/g' file > result
```

But the same command split into two steps works:

Step 1:

```sh
sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{0,127\}$/& /;ta' -e '1,46d' \
-e '/Pharmacom/,+5d' -e 's/^M//g'  FILE > step
```

Step 2:

```sh
sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' -e 's/---*/\n/g' step > result
```

Comment: Are you using sed on MacOS?

Comment: I'm using linux Ubuntu (4.2.0-36-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:05:35 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

Comment: Then it'd be useful to know what "doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I first translated your commands to something readable so I could make sense of it:

```sh
# Pad lines with spaces until 128 characters long
:a
s/^.\{0,127\}$/& /
ta

# Delete first 46 lines
1,46d

# Delete line containing 'Pharmacom' and next five lines
/Pharmacom/,+5d

# Remove carriage returns
s/^M//g

# Join rest of lines on single line
:a
N
$!ba
s/\n//g

# Replace two or more dashes with a newline
s/---*/\n/g
```

Then I reduced it to the problematic parts:

```sh
# Pad lines with spaces until 128 characters long
:a
s/^.\{0,127\}$/& /
ta

# Join rest of lines on single line
:a
N
$!ba
s/\n//g
```

Or, on a single line:

```sh
sed ':a;s/^.\{0,127\}$/& /;ta;:a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g'
```

The problem is that you **use the same label name twice**, so instead of repeating your first `s` command, the `ta` command jumps to the second label `:a`, and instead of padding to 128 characters, you get just a single space inserted.

This is easily fixed by using two different label names:

```sh
sed ':a;s/^.\{0,127\}$/& /;ta;:b;N;$!bb;s/\n//g'
```

Two remarks:

- It doesn't matter if you use `sed -e '...' -e '...'` or `sed '...;...'` in this context; they both count as a single command and label names have to be unique.
- I'd move the `d` commands to the beginning of the script, or you do all the padding work for nothing on the lines you're deleting anyways.